# Is it possible to default to self-hosted runners?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I am planning to move from GitLab to GitHub and just started to experiment with GH Actions.

One thing I see is that I have to indicate that I want to run on a self-hosted runner **for each job**.

Is there a way to set a default for the Organization, or have it defined only once in the workflow YAML file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so.  This is just another attribute that you need to consider when specifying a place for a job to run.  For example, you already need to specify what type of system (e.g., OS and version) you want to use for each job via the `runs-on` directive, since there's no reasonable way to guess, so specifying self-hosted instead isn't exceptionally burdensome.

Comment: You do not need to specify which OS to run when using a self-hosted runner.

Comment: You need to specify a `runs-on` directive either way.  If you were not using a self-hosted runner, you'd still have to specify on what type of system you'd want to run on.